# FileNotFoundError while installing the module jpy via pip in conda

Tags: python, linux, anaconda, linux-mint

I work in anaconda (python 3.4) and I'm using Linux Min 18.
I tried to get the module `jpy` with `pip install -i https://pypi.anaconda.org/pypi/simple jpy`, but I got the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-p2voq_f8/jpy/setup.py", line 100, in <module>
        with open('README.rst') as file:
    FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'README.rst'
```

And I know what the problem is, but not how to solve it. I tried to update my setuptools with `pip install -U setuptools pip` but the main problem is still there. And to google it was not helpful for me.

Any ideas? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

grabbed from github:

First download the repository

> Install a JDK 8, preferrably the Oracle distribution. Set JDK_HOME or
>   JPY_JDK_HOME to point to your JDK installation and run the build
>   script:
>
> ```
> $ export JAVA_HOME=<your-jdk-dir> 
> $ python get-pip.py 
> $ python setup.py --maven bdist_wheel
> ```
>
> On success, the wheel is found in the
>   dist directory.
>
> To deploy the jpy.jar (if you don't know why you need this step, this
>   is not for you):
>
> `$ mvn clean deploy -DskipTests=true`

https://github.com/bcdev/jpy

Comment: This changes nothing about the FileNotFound-Error.

Comment: What os are u using?

Comment: Linux Mint 18. I added it to my question.

Comment: Nope, got the same FileNotFound-Error as usual.

Comment: Ok. I'm not sure if I have done something like this before: First I installed JDK with the following instruction [x] (https://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/1372) and after that I created a symbolic link with `ln -s /opt/java/jdk1.8.0_111 /opt/java/latest` and while beeing in opt/java I set `export JDK_HOME=/opt/java/latest
                                            export JAVA_HOME=${JDK_HOME}
                                            export PATH=$PATH:${JAVA_HOME}/bin` ....

Comment: Ok, I tried to do this but after `python get-pip.py` it says that there isn't any file called 'get-pip.py' .